# Asymptotics for a recurrence relation

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Here we have $T(1)=1$ and
$$T(n)=T(n-1)+T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+n.$$
How to show its asymptotics? I suppose it's $n^{\Theta(\log n)}$, but not sure.

For the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450802/strange-recurrence-what-is-it-asymptotic-to/), there's no term $n$ in the summation, and I found it hard to reduce my question to it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475081/upper-bound-for-tn-tn-1-tn-2-n-with-recursion-tree

Comment: @Vaidyanathan Thank you. My question might be duplicated. But in your link, there's no detail for the derivation of this bound. What's the thinking process?

Comment: In 2015 the linked question also was marked as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518682/solve-tn-tn-1t-fracn2n) question. It has four answers, but has $n/2$ instead of $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, so I am not perfectly sure that they are suitable for this question.